# Put config variables into php file

Tags: php, file, variables, config, file-put-contents

The system I'm working on has its own installation page to configure database connection. Basically, the user is filling some `$_POST` fields like `host, dbname, password` etc.. then once he proceed further I want to store all of this variables in a file.

The final file should goes like this:

```
<?php
    $config["db"]["host"] = "host";
    $config["db"]["username"] = "user";
    $config["db"]["password"] = "user_pass";
 ?>
```

But no matter what, the output is like this:

```
<?php
    $config["db"]["host"] = "";
    $config["db"]["username"] = "";
    $config["db"]["password"] = "";
?>
```

So it seems that all data from last quotes disappears. 
This is my code:

```
$file = 'core/database.core.php';

    $content = "<?php \r\n";
    $content .= '$config["db"]["host"] = "' . $_POST['db_host'] . '";' . "\r\n";
    $content .= '$config["db"]["username"] = "' . $_POST['db_user'] . '";' . "\r\n";
    $content .= '$config["db"]["password"] = "' . $_POST['db_pass'] . '";' . "\r\n";
    $content .= "?>";

file_put_contents($file, $content);
```

Var dump of $content variable outputs only this:

`string(114) ""`

The source code in browser show this:

```
string(114) "<?php 
$config["db"]["host"] = "127.0.0.1";
$config["db"]["username"] = "";
$config["db"]["password"] = "";
?>"
```

I've been trying in many ways and I have no idea how can i figure it out to work properly the way i want to achieve. Any suggestions?

Comment: php tag is getting executed so.

Comment: the var dump shows you that $content is a string of 114 chars. The reason you don't see the content, is that you probably view this with your browser where everything between <?php and ?> is not displayed. Open the source code in your browser. Try also to do var_dump($_POST) to ensure that the post data is transmitted correctly.

Comment: @esel the $_POST data contains everything it should contain. In fact, yes - source code in browser show it. Main post edited.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use var_export();

```
    $config["db"]["host"] = $_POST['db_host'];
    $config["db"]["username"] = $_POST['db_user'];
    $config["db"]["password"] = $_POST['db_pass'];

  $content = "<?php ".PHP_EOL." \$config = ".var_export($config,true)."; ".PHP_EOL." ?>";
```

If that wont work, check first if all fields are set right!!!

Comment: But what **esel** says about the source code is your problem here ;)  Test it without the first '<?php ' in your code

Comment: Or do **print htmlentities(var_dump($arr,true));** to see the code you have created.

Comment: its adviseable to view text files as they are ment to: `header('Content-Type: text/plain')` - instead of trying to get html to behave like text

Comment: @birdspider This was just an developing / debugging hint ;)